# Enabling Edit Tab Ribbon Controls for List New/Edit forms in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, ribbon, display-form, edit-form

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" Src="~/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="MUISelector" Src="~/_controltemplates/MUISelector.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="DesignModeConsole" Src="~/_controltemplates/DesignModeConsole.ascx" %>

" dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%>"
runat="server" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" __expr-val-dir="ltr">

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _fV4UI = true;
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/SCB/recert/css/icons.css" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" name="MasterPages.App_UiV4_V1.css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>

<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Language="javascript" Name="core.js" Defer="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Language="javascript" Name="masterpages.app_uiv4_v1.js" Defer="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/forms.css" />
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/Sharepoint.MasterPages/favicon.ico"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:SPPageManager runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SPHelpPageComponent Visible="false" runat="server"/>
```

```
 <!-- <div class="i4-bodyDrop s4-notdlg"></div>
<div class="i4-leftDrop s4-notdlg"></div>
<div class="i4-rightDrop s4-notdlg"></div> -->


<form runat="server" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}">
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true"
    EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />

<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager ID="m" runat="Server"/>
<SharePoint:SPNoScript runat="server"/>
<div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display: none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-TurnOnAcc" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
        <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%>"
            EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display: none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-TurnOffAcc" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
        <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%>"
            EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div class="s4-notdlg s4-skipribbonshortcut noindex">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:this.href='#startNavigation';" class="ms-SkiptoNavigation"
        accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,skipribbon_accesskey%>" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,skipRibbonCommandsLink%>"
            EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:this.href='#mainContent';" class="ms-SkiptoMainContent"
        accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,maincontent_accesskey%>" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,mainContentLink%>"
            EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<a id="HiddenAnchor" href="javascript:;" style="display: none;"></a>



<div id="ribbonContainerBackground" class="s4-notdlg">
    <div id="s4-ribbonrow-background" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
        <div class="i4-topDrop s4-notdlg" > </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="i4-icseal" class=" s4-notdlg">
    <SharePoint:SPLinkButton ID="SPLinkButton1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/">
        <div id="i4-icseal-link" title="Return to Top Level">
        </div>
    </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
</div>

<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="GlobalNavigation"/>

    <div id="s4-ribboncont">            
        <div class="ms-siteactionscontainer s4-notdlg">
            <span class="ms-siteactionsmenu" id="siteactiontd">
                <SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>"
                    ID="SiteActionsMenuMain" PrefixHtml="" SuffixHtml="" MenuNotVisibleHtml="&amp;nbsp;">
                    <CustomTemplate>
                        <SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate runat="server" FeatureScope="Site" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
                            GroupId="SiteActions" UseShortId="true">
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_EditPage" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpage%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescriptionv4%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsEditPage.png"
                                MenuGroupId="100" Sequence="110" ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(false);" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_TakeOffline" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_takeoffline%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_takeofflinedescription%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/connecttospworkspace32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="100" Sequence="120" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_CreatePage" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createpage%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createpagedesc%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/NewContentPageHH.png"
                                MenuGroupId="200" Sequence="210" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('Page')) { OpenCreateWebPageDialog('~site/_layouts/createwebpage.aspx') }"
                                PermissionsString="AddListItems, EditListItems" PermissionMode="All" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_CreateDocLib" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdoclib%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdoclibdesc%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/NewDocLibHH.png"
                                MenuGroupId="200" Sequence="220" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('DocLib')) { GoToPage('~site/_layouts/new.aspx?FeatureId={00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101}&amp;ListTemplate=101') }"
                                PermissionsString="ManageLists" PermissionMode="Any" VisibilityFeatureId="00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_CreateSite" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createsite%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createsitedesc%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/newweb32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="200" Sequence="230" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('Site')) { STSNavigate('~site/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx') }"
                                PermissionsString="ManageSubwebs,ViewFormPages" PermissionMode="All" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_Create" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_create%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdesc%>" MenuGroupId="200" Sequence="240"
                                UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('All')) { STSNavigate('~site/_layouts/create.aspx') }"
                                PermissionsString="ManageLists, ManageSubwebs" PermissionMode="Any" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents" Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/allcontent32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300" Sequence="302" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"
                                PermissionsString="ViewFormPages" PermissionMode="Any" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_EditSite" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editsite%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editsitedescription%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/SharePointDesigner32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300" Sequence="304" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="EditInSPD('~site/',true);"
                                PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages" PermissionMode="Any" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_SitePermissions" Text="<%$Resources:wss,people_sitepermissions%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sitepermissiondescriptionv4%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/Permissions32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300" Sequence="310" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/user.aspx"
                                PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions" PermissionMode="Any" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_Settings" Text="<%$Resources:wss,settings_pagetitle%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sitesettingsdescriptionv4%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/settingsIcon.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300" Sequence="320" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/settings.aspx"
                                PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
                                PermissionMode="Any" />
                            <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_CommitNewUI" Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_commitnewui%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_commitnewuidescription%>" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/visualupgradehh.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300" Sequence="330" UseShortId="true" ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="GoToPage('~site/_layouts/prjsetng.aspx')"
                                PermissionsString="ManageWeb" PermissionMode="Any" ShowOnlyIfUIVersionConfigurationEnabled="true" />
                        </SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate>
                    </CustomTemplate>
                </SharePoint:SiteActions>
            </span>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:PopoutMenu runat="server" ID="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                    IconAlt="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbIconAlt%>" IconOffsetX="0" IconOffsetY="112"
                    IconWidth="16" IconHeight="16" AnchorCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor" AnchorOpenCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor-open"
                    MenuCss="s4-breadcrumb-menu" Visible="false">
                    <div class="s4-breadcrumb-top" style="display:none">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="s4-breadcrumb-header" Text="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbHeader%>" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
                        <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
                            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" PathSeparator="" CssClass="s4-breadcrumb" NodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbNode"
                            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbRootNode"
                            NodeImageOffsetX="0" NodeImageOffsetY="353" NodeImageWidth="16" NodeImageHeight="16"
                            NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" RTLNodeImageOffsetX="0" RTLNodeImageOffsetY="376"
                            RTLNodeImageWidth="16" RTLNodeImageHeight="16" RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                            HideInteriorRootNodes="true" SkipLinkText=""  Visible="false"/>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
                <div class="s4-die" style="display:none">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <SharePoint:PageStateActionButton ID="PageStateActionButton" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
        </div>
        <div class="s4-trc-container s4-notdlg">
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ID="GlobalDelegate0" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink0"/>
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="display: none"></a><a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="display: none">
            </a><span>
                <SharePoint:DeveloperDashboardLauncher ID="DeveloperDashboardLauncher" NavigateUrl="javascript:ToggleDeveloperDashboard()"
                    runat="server" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" Text="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_launchdevdashalt_text%>"
                    OffsetX="0" OffsetY="222" Height="16" Width="16"/>
            </span>

            <div class="i4-help">
                <span style="height: 17px; width: 17px; position: relative; display: inline-block;
                    overflow: hidden;" class="s4-clust"><a href="#" style="height: 17px; width: 17px;
                        display: inline-block;" onclick="TopHelpButtonClick('HelpHome');return false"
                        accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>" id="TopHelpLink"
                        title="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server">
                        <img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" alt="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>"
                            style="left: -0px !important; top: -309px !important; position: absolute;" align="absmiddle"
                            border="0" runat="server" />
                </a></span>
            </div>

            <div class="i4-welcome" id="i4-welcome">
                <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                </wssuc:Welcome>
                <wssuc:MUISelector ID="IdMuiSelector" runat="server"/>  
            </div>

            <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" ID="GlobalDelegate2" Scope="Farm"
                runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <SharePoint:SPRibbon runat="server" PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer" CssFile="">
            <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowLeft"
                CssClass="s4-notdlg">
            </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
            <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowRight"
                ID="RibbonTabRowRight"
                CssClass="s4-notdlg">
            </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
        </SharePoint:SPRibbon>
    </div>
    <div id="notificationArea" class="s4-noti">
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SPNavigation" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PublishingConsole" ID="PublishingConsoleDelegate">
        </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div id="WebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="WebPartAdderUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"
            runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <WebPartPages:WebPartAdder ID="WebPartAdder" runat="server"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:postbacktrigger ControlID="WebPartAdder" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div> 


<div id="s4-workspace" class="s4-nosetwidth">
    <div class="i4-workspaceBackground s4-notdlg"></div>
    <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
        <div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle i4-titlerow">
            <div class="s4-title s4-lp i4-title">

                <div class="s4-title-inner i4-title-inner" >
                    <div id="s4-searcharea" class="s4-search s4-rp" style="margin-right:20px">
                            <a href="/"><strong>Master| </strong></a>
                            <strong>SRCTT | </strong></a>-->
                            <a href="/sites/rsv/SitePages/Land2.aspx"><strong>Reservation</strong></a>
                    </div> 

                    <div id="s4-searcharea" class="s4-search s4-rp" style="margin-right:40px">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
                            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"/>
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">

   <ASP:SITEMAPPATH runat="server" hideinteriorrootnodes="true" rootnodestyle-cssclass="breadcrumbRootNode" currentnodestyle-cssclass="breadcrumbCurrentNode" nodestyle-cssclass="breadcrumbNode" rendercurrentnodeaslink="true" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider">
```

```
                               <!-- <asp:SiteMapPath
 runat="server"
 SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
 RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
 NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode"
 CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode"
 RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode"
 HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
 SkipLinkText="" __designer:Preview="&lt;span SiteMapProviders=&quot;SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider&quot; HideInteriorRootNodes=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;a title=&quot;Root Node&quot; class=&quot;breadcrumbRootNode&quot; Href=&quot;/_vti_bin/Root%20Node%20url&quot;&gt;Root Node&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt; &amp;gt; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;a title=&quot;Parent Node&quot; class=&quot;breadcrumbNode&quot; Href=&quot;/_vti_bin/Parent%20Nodeurl&quot;&gt;Parent Node&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt; &amp;gt; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;breadcrumbCurrentNode&quot;&gt;Current Node&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='SkipLinkText' R='-1' /&gt;&lt;P N='HasAttributes' T='True' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl26' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;" __designer:Templates="&lt;Group Name=&quot;NodeTemplate&quot;&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;NodeTemplate&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Group&gt;&lt;Group Name=&quot;CurrentNodeTemplate&quot;&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;CurrentNodeTemplate&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Group&gt;&lt;Group Name=&quot;RootNodeTemplate&quot;&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;RootNodeTemplate&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Group&gt;&lt;Group Name=&quot;PathSeparatorTemplate&quot;&gt;&lt;Template Name=&quot;PathSeparatorTemplate&quot; Content=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Group&gt;"/>-->
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </h1>
                        <span id="onetidPageTitleSeparator" class="s4-nothome s4-bcsep s4-titlesep">
                            <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/>
                        </span>
                        <h2>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
                        </h2>
                        <div class="s4-pagedescription i4-pagedescription" tabindex="0">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="s4-pr s4-notdlg">
                <a name="startNavigation"></a>
                <div class="s4-rp">
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3-mini"
                        Scope="Farm" runat="server"/>
                </div>
                <div class="s4-lp i4-toplinks">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                        <h2 class="ms-hidden">
                            <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,topnav_pagetitle%>"
                                EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></h2>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server">
                            <SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenuV4" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
                                DataSourceID="topSiteMap" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                                UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCSS="true" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                                MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-tn"/>
                            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" ID="topNavigationDelegate">
                                <Template_Controls>
                                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                                        ID="topSiteMap" runat="server" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002" />
                                </Template_Controls>
                            </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="s4-statusbarcontainer">
            <div id="pageStatusBar" class="s4-status-s1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <SharePoint:VisualUpgradePreviewStatus runat="server"/>
        <div id="s4-mainarea">
            <div id="s4-leftpanel" class="s4-notdlg">
                <div id="ic4-ql-drop-bb">
                    <div id="s4-leftpanel-content">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" runat="server" />
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server" />
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" runat="server" />
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">
                            <div class="ms-quicklaunchouter">
                                <div class="ms-quickLaunch">
                                    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="4">
                                        <contenttemplate>
                                            <h2 style="display:inline;" class="ms-hidden"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></h2>
                                        </contenttemplate>
                                    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" runat="server">
                                        <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server">
                                            <contenttemplate>
                                                <h3 class="ms-standardheader"><label class="ms-hidden"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></label>
                                                <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="ViewFormPages">
                                                    <div class="ms-quicklaunchheader"><SharePoint:SPLinkButton id="idNavLinkViewAll" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx" Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent%>" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/></div>
                                                </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
                                                </h3>
                                            </contenttemplate>
                                        </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                    <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager ID="QuickLaunchNavigationManager" runat="server"
                                        QuickLaunchControlId="QuickLaunchMenu" ContainedControl="QuickLaunch" EnableViewState="false"
                                        CssClass="ms-quicklaunch-navmgr">
                                        <div>
                                            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
                                                <Template_Controls>
```

We are using Custom Master Page for SharePoint 2010
In the **NewForm.aspx** When creating a new item and selecting the **"Comments"** field (which is a Multiple Line type column) a thin portion of the ribbon tabs are exposed just under the webpart title.  If a user select any of the other field such as Title, or Date then it is fine.

This is an out of the box “NewForm.aspx” NOT a Custom Form.The problem is only for this Comments (multiple line field) when it is selected, not with any other field.

The problem is only if we apply the Custom Master Page.
If disable the Custom Master Page and apply the **v4.master** page then the problem is resolved.

So it looks like that the Custom Master Page creating the issue:

When I disable the Custom Mater Page and apply the v4.master page then at works fine as following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what problem or issue occured?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the customized master page, we have no way to figure out what is happening (the page and the form are both built from the same master).

I would try making a custom master page that is an exact copy of v4. The issue will likely not recur. From there, add your custom changes back one by one to isolate what is causing this.

Comment: Hello habboy I have add the master page in my question now.